# Code intended to loop however it does not

Tags: python

Why isn't this code looping?

```py
while True:
  for i in text:
    print (ord(i))
    print (i , "=" , chr (ord(i) +n))
    password = (password + chr (ord(i) + n))

  if (text.lower() != text):
    print ("only lower case.")

  elif (n<2 or n>15):
    print ("your code must be between 2 and 15, including them.")

    return False

  else:
    print(text ,  "=>"  , password)
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting to make it more easily readable

Comment: I don't see anywhere in here where the user is asked for more info.  Could you explain in more detail what you expect this code to do?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your codes initial input or expected output.  But going from your code's format alone, your 'if' statments are outside the scope of the While Loop.  Please look:

```
while True:          
    for i in text:
        print (ord(i))
        print (i , "=" , chr (ord(i) +n))
        password = (password + chr (ord(i) + n))

if (text.lower() != text):
    print ("only lower case.")
elif (n<2 or n>15):
    print ("your code must be between 2 and 15, including them.")
    return False
else:
    print(text ,  "=>"  , password)
```

Is NOT the same as:

```
while True:          
    for i in text:
        print (ord(i))
        print (i , "=" , chr (ord(i) +n))
        password = (password + chr (ord(i) + n))

    if (text.lower() != text):
        print ("only lower case.")
    elif (n<2 or n>15):
        print ("your code must be between 2 and 15, including them.")
        return False
    else:
        print(text ,  " => "  , password)
```

Also on your 'else' statement, I'm assuming this is the case where your While Loop should break, so I'd add a 'break' keyword.